# Type stability for a function involving case distinctions

Tags: julia, generic-programming

I am writing a function which computes the weights for the barycentric interpolation formula. Ignoring type stability, that's easy enough:

```
function baryweights(x)
    n = length(x)
    if n == 1; return [1.0]; end # This is obviously not type stable

    xmin,xmax = extrema(x)
    x *= 4/(xmax-xmin)
    # ^ Multiply by capacity of interval to avoid overflow
    return [
        1/prod(x[i]-x[j] for j in 1:n if j != i)
        for i = 1:n
    ]
end
```

The problem for type stability is to work out the return type of the `n > 1` case so I can return an array of the correct type in the `n == 1` case. Is there an easy trick to achieve this?

Comment: What is expected result? Because if I call `baryweights([1,2,3])` means parameter is `Array{Int}` result is `Array{Float64}`! Is really the problem on line you are pointing out?

Comment: Yes, that is desired. I want the return type to be whatever the `n > 1` case returns, but it should be so for any value of `n = 1`, including `n == 1`.

Comment: But what is use case? I tried complex numbers but it don't work with `extrema` function. Could you show some examples where types differ from expectation?

Comment: `Int`s as input would be a case I want to support. And maybe complex numbers as well, once I fixed the extrema issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call the function recursively on a dummy argument:

```
function baryweights(x)
    n = length(x)
    if n == 1
        T = eltype(baryweights(zeros(eltype(x),2)))
        return [one(T)]
    end

    xmin,xmax = extrema(x)
    let x = 4/(xmax-xmin) * x
        # ^ Multiply by capacity of interval to avoid overflow,
        #   and wrap in let to avoid another source of type instability
        #   (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15276)
        return [
            1/prod(x[i]-x[j] for j in 1:n if j != i)
            for i = 1:n
        ]
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you test it? You probably meant `T = eltype(baryweights(zeros(eltype(x),2)))`?

Comment: Right. No, I once again failed to see the forest behind all the trees and forgot to test. I'll look into it

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand your plans. But maybe something like this could help? ->

```
baryone(t::T) where T<:Real = [1.]
baryone(t::T) where T<:Complex = [1im]  # or whatever you like here

function baryweights(x::Array{T,1}) where T<:Number
    n = length(x)
    n == 1 && return baryone(x[1])
    xmin,xmax = extrema(x)  # don't forget fix extrema for complex! :)
    x *= 4/(xmax-xmin)
    # ^ Multiply by capacity of interval to avoid overflow
    return [
        1/prod(x[i]-x[j] for j in 1:n if j != i)
        for i = 1:n
    ]
end
```

Warning: I am still newbie! If I try `@code_warntype baryweights([1])` I just see plenty of warnings. (Also if I avoid calling `baryone`). For example `n` is `Any` !!

Edit:
I [asked on discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/help-newbie-to-understand-type-stability-please/7119/2) and now see that `@code_warn` return much better result if we use another variable (y):

```
function baryweights(x::Array{T,1}) where T<:Number
    n = length(x)
    n == 1 && return baryone(x[1])
    xmin,xmax = extrema(x)  # don't forget fix extrema for complex! :)
    let y = x * 4/(xmax-xmin)
        # ^ Multiply by capacity of interval to avoid overflow
        return [
            1/prod(y[i]-y[j] for j in 1:n if j != i)
            for i = 1:n
        ]
    end
end
```

Edit2: I added `let` to avoid `y` to be `Core.Box`ed

Comment: Thanks lot for your interest in this problem! I wasn't aware that the closure introduced another type instability, and you pointing out the `let` work-around saved me a lot of time of googling around!

Comment: Now as to what I want to achieve: I want to be sure that the `n == 1` case returns exactly the same type as the other cases, no matter what the input type is. Your work-around works if there was a finite and known set of cases to consider, but even then I would have to list them all, which is tedious, error-prone and hard to maintain. The trick with my solution is that I can guarantee the return type to be the same, no matter what type you feed into my function.